# Sort nodes by latest comments on it

Tags: 7, comments, views

I am using D7. I want to sort the nodes by the comment post date on it.

**Like**

Node `a` created on Jan 03
Node `b` Created on Jan 05

Normally i can sort it either `asc` or `desc`.

What i want is a node with latest comment will be in top of my views.

I am looking for a views3 solution. 
Is it possible ?

Comment: In Drupal almost everything you can think of is possible! The only question remains HOW?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Last comment time" is sort.

[image: views Last comment time]

Then use 'Sort descending'

[image]

Comment: How to sort nodes by count of posted comments..  using EQF ?

Answer (score 2):

Add the comment table in a relationship, "Last comment time" should just show up.

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be to add the *Comments of the node* relationship. You can find this under the *Comment* section in the *Relationships* block in the Views UI (when the base table of your view is `{node}`). You will now be able to add the *Comment: Post date* as a filter and make it sort by *desc* which should do the trick for you.

Depending on your use-case, you can *then* consider doing the following:

- Making the relationship "required" if you wan't to exclude nodes that don't have comments on them as yet.
- Set `Use aggregation: Yes` if you'd like to just show only the most recent comment of a node and not any other i.e. nodes don't repeat themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Import this view:

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'newcomments';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'newcomments';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0-alpha1';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'newcomments';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['hide_empty'] = 0;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['link_to_node'] = 1;
/* Field: Content: Updated/commented date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['id'] = 'last_updated';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['table'] = 'node_comment_statistics';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['field'] = 'last_updated';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['element_label_colon'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['last_updated']['date_format'] = 'long';
/* Field: Content: Comment count */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['id'] = 'comment_count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['table'] = 'node_comment_statistics';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['field'] = 'comment_count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['element_label_colon'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['format_plural'] = 0;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Updated/commented date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['last_updated']['id'] = 'last_updated';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['last_updated']['table'] = 'node_comment_statistics';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['last_updated']['field'] = 'last_updated';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['last_updated']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'newcomments';

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '5';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$translatables['newcomments'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('newcomments'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('Updated/commented date'),
  t('Comment count'),
  t('.'),
  t(','),
  t('Page'),
  t('Block'),
);
```